# ReportViewer how to display a boolean value differently

Tags: visual-studio-2010, boolean, reportviewer

My data is stored in BIT field in SQL server (0 or 1)
When I display it in reportviewer it shows TRUE or FALSE

I would like to change it to YES or NO
Please advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change it in the report using iif.

```
=iif(Fields!YourBool.Value, "Yes", "No")
```

If your data is null then it will evaluate to "No".  If you want it do be blank instead use this one

```
=iif(isnothing(Fields!YourBool.Value), "", iif(Fields!YourBool.Value, "Yes", "No"))
```

Comment: where should i put this formula, in the format poperty of my cell ?

Comment: Right click on the cell and click Expression...  Make sure to change "YourBool" in the code example to the correct field name for your report.

Answer (score 1):

and also you can display checkbox :

(change the textbox’s font to Wingdings2)

```
=IIf( Fields!MyBooleanField.Value, Chr(82), Chr(163))
```